# how to define N bus with width 32bit

Tags: verilog

I wanted to define large number of bus with bus width 32bit.

for example

```
input [31:0] a0, a1, a2, .... aN;
input [31:0] b0, b1, b2, .... bN;
output [31:0] c0, c1, c2, .... cN;

c0 = a0 + b0;
c1 = a1 + b1;
.
.
cN = aN + bN;
```

how can I realize this code with iteration?

Comment: How about using arrays and flatten them? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369698/how-to-pass-array-structure-between-two-verilog-modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog Generates are designed for solving this issue. It would be easier if you can use unpacked arrays for ports.

Statements need to be contained in an `initial` or `always`, to imply the output is a flip-flop use `always @(posedge clk)` for a combinatorial circuit use `always @*`.

```
module example (
  parameter N = 10
)(
input             clk,
input      [31:0] a [0:N],
input      [31:0] b [0:N],
output reg [31:0] c [0:N]
);

genvar i;
generate
for(i=0; i<=N; i++) begin
  always @(posedge clk) begin
      c[i] <= a[i] + b[i];
  end
end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

Generates are good when you need to parameterise module instance, the above can be rewritten with a plain for loop.

```
integer i;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  for(i=0; i<=N; i++) begin
    c[i] <= a[i] + b[i];
  end
end
```

For synthesizable code the for loop must be able to be statically unrolled.